# Simulate click on a div that has certain class and certain id

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to achieve (with jQuery) is this:

```
  $('#123').closest('.sender').trigger( "click" );
```

To simulate a click on a CLASS "sender" that is a class of a div with ID "123"

```
<div id="123" class="sender"></div>
```

UPDATE: Thanks to Pranav this has been sorted. Here is the result for those who need it:
https://jsfiddle.net/d35zzhcz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method is using to get the closest ancestor element. In your case, you can combine the selectors or use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method instead of [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

```
$('#123.sender').trigger( "click" );
// or
$('#123').filter('.sender').trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav. You were the first. any ideas why this doesn't fire the ajax request (placed on .sender click)
anyway - thanks , man!

Comment: @Rossitten : is it dynamically generated? and where are you binding the handler?

Comment: @Rossitten : although you need to prevent the default action within the handler using `event.preventDefault()` or by returning `false` at the end

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to query a specific element with the ID "123" which also has the class "sender".

In jquery you can do this with:

```
$('#123.sender').click(function(){
  // things you want to do here.
});
```

This will add a listener to whatever element you assign it to.

If you'd like for this to be more general (all .sender classes, for example), you can do:

```
$('.sender').click(function(){
    // example will add a class to an element which has foo, but only this element
    $(this).addClass('foo');
});
```

I would also like to add that for UX purposes, if you use a DIV element, you should also add to your CSS rules:

```
.sender {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

This will let the user know it is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to combine the id of the div with its class.

```
$('#123.sender').on('click', function(){
   // your code goes here...
});
```